# .NET Mutext.ReleaseMutex and Mutex.Close

Tags: .net, mutex, release

What's the difference between the two? If I do `Mutex.Close()` instead of `Mutex.Release()` when shutting down my app, what would be the side effect?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[ReleaseMutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex.releasemutex) is used to allow another thread to obtain the mutex. It should only be called if you have acquired the mutex (called `WaitOne` and acquired it or acquired through the constructor). **Important Note** `ReleaseMutex` will throw an exception if you have not acquired the mutex.

[Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.close) is used to clean up the resources that have been allocated by declaring the mutex object, whether you ever blocked on it or not, if you have acquired the mutex it will release it (equivalent to calling `ReleaseMutex`. If you plan to lock on the mutex for the whole application (i.e. using this to ensure a single instance of your app), then I would wrap it in a using statement like the example in [Joseph Albahari's](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Mutex) threading guide (a must read).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I took your advice and changed `Mutex.ReleaseMutex()` to `Mutex.Close()` in my solution ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367452/clickonce-application-doesnt-restart-after-upgrade-is-complete/22604449#22604449)) to the collision between VB's Application Framework and the ClickOnce API.