# Clickonce application doesn't restart after upgrade is complete

Tags: vb.net, clickonce, restart

I am using [AppplicationDeployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.aspx) class to check if upgrade is available and then upgrade the app like below

```
Dim AD As System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment = System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment
Dim info As System.Deployment.Application.UpdateCheckInfo = Nothing

Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
Me.Close()

AD.Update()

Application.Restart() // this doesn't work which is still ok.
```

The restart doesn't work so I am trying to get the upgraded application executable path and update the registry so when user re-starts the system the latest application will be launched.

I am not able to get the path where the application is installed after upgrading. It creates new folder in the c\document...\user.... I know. But, need to get this path and update registry.

Anyone has any pointers?

Comment: What do you mean the restart doesn't work?  What happens?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because you're using VB's native Single-Instance Application feature in your ClickOnce-deployed app. The feature uses a `Mutex` under the hood, which doesn't get released in time for the app to restart. Thus the behavior you're seeing--it doesn't restart.

I had the same problem just now. To fix it I had to use a VB translation and slight reworking of the trick I found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32908/). In essence what we need is a shared instance of `Mutex` and a 3-second pause on `Application.Restart()` to give the exiting version time to release its `Mutex`. Don't forget to UNCHECK *'Make single instance application'* on the Application tab of your project's Property Pages.

[image]

Here's the code I ended up with, below. This way we can have the best of all worlds--VB's nifty Application Framework that we enjoy so much, Single-Instance functionality and ClickOnce API restarts. All at once. I'm giddy.

Hat tip #1: To *devzoo*, for his [CodeProject posting](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32908/), demonstrating the main concept.

Hat tip #2: To *NullFX*, for his [WinApi PostMessage() idea](http://sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html), as quoted by *devzoo*.

Hat tip #3: To *@cmptrs4now* for his `IsRestarting` 3-second pause idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95098/).

Hat tip #4: To *@pstrjds* for his clarification [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519465/net-mutext-releasemutex-and-mutex-close). Per his advice I changed `Mutex.ReleaseMutex()` to `Mutex.Close()` below. This looks to be safer.

HTH

```
Friend Class Main
  Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

  Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef Message As Message)
    If Message.Msg = SingleInstance.WM_SHOWFIRSTINSTANCE Then
      ShowWindow()
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(Message)
  End Sub

  Private Sub ShowWindow()
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    Me.Focus()
  End Sub

  Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdUpdate.Click
    If ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed Then
      If ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CheckForUpdate(False)
        ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.Update()

        MsgBox("The application has been updated and will now restart.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

        My.Settings.IsRestarting = True
        My.Settings.Save()

        Application.Restart()
      End If
    End If
  End Sub
End Class

Namespace My
  ' The following events are availble for MyApplication:
  ' 
  ' Startup: Raised when the application starts, before the startup form is created.
  ' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
  ' UnhandledException: Raised if the application encounters an unhandled exception.
  ' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active. 
  ' NetworkAvailabilityChanged: Raised when the network connection is connected or disconnected.
  Partial Friend Class MyApplication
    Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
      If My.Settings.IsRestarting Then
        My.Settings.IsRestarting = False
        My.Settings.Save()
        Thread.Sleep(3000)
      End If

      If Not SingleInstance.Start() Then
        SingleInstance.ShowFirstInstance()
        e.Cancel = True
      End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyApplication_Shutdown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shutdown
      SingleInstance.Stop()
    End Sub
  End Class
End Namespace

Public NotInheritable Class SingleInstance
  Public Shared ReadOnly WM_SHOWFIRSTINSTANCE As Integer = WinApi.RegisterWindowMessage("WM_SHOWFIRSTINSTANCE|{0}", ProgramInfo.AssemblyGuid)
  Private Shared Mutex As Mutex

  Public Shared Function Start() As Boolean
    Dim lIsOnlyInstance As Boolean
    Dim sMutexName As String

    lIsOnlyInstance = False
    sMutexName = String.Format("Local\{0}", ProgramInfo.AssemblyGuid)

    ' If you want your app to be limited to a single instance
    ' across ALL SESSIONS (multiple users & terminal services),
    ' then use the following line instead:
    ' sMutexName = String.Format("Global\\{0}", ProgramInfo.AssemblyGuid);

    Mutex = New Mutex(True, sMutexName, lIsOnlyInstance)
    Return lIsOnlyInstance
  End Function

  Public Shared Sub ShowFirstInstance()
    WinApi.PostMessage(New IntPtr(WinApi.HWND_BROADCAST), WM_SHOWFIRSTINSTANCE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
  End Sub

  Public Shared Sub [Stop]()
    Mutex.Close()
  End Sub
End Class

Public NotInheritable Class WinApi
  <DllImport("user32")> _
  Public Shared Function RegisterWindowMessage(message As String) As Integer
  End Function

  <DllImport("user32")> _
  Public Shared Function PostMessage(hwnd As IntPtr, msg As Integer, wparam As IntPtr, lparam As IntPtr) As Boolean
  End Function

  <DllImport("user32")> _
  Public Shared Function ShowWindow(hWnd As IntPtr, nCmdShow As Integer) As Boolean
  End Function

  <DllImport("user32")> _
  Public Shared Function SetForegroundWindow(hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
  End Function

  Public Shared Function RegisterWindowMessage(Template As String, ParamArray Values As Object()) As Integer
    Return RegisterWindowMessage(String.Format(Template, Values))
  End Function

  Public Shared Sub ShowToFront(Window As IntPtr)
    ShowWindow(Window, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
    SetForegroundWindow(Window)
  End Sub

  Public Const HWND_BROADCAST As Integer = &HFFFF
  Public Const SW_SHOWNORMAL As Integer = 1
End Class

Public NotInheritable Class ProgramInfo
  Public Shared ReadOnly Property AssemblyGuid As String
    Get
      Dim aAttributes As Object()

      aAttributes = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(GuidAttribute), False)

      If aAttributes.Length = 0 Then
        AssemblyGuid = String.Empty
      Else
        AssemblyGuid = DirectCast(aAttributes(0), GuidAttribute).Value
      End If
    End Get
  End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try restarting the application like so:

```
Dim applicationEntryPoint = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdatedApplicationFullName

Process.Start(applicationEntryPoint)

// Call any code to shut down the current instance of the application here...
```

Comment: No, this also doesn't work. Is there any way to get the upgraded executable path?

Comment: Instead of saving application executable path, I saved below path to registry..which resolved my problem.    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs) + "\Your publisher\app_name.appref-ms"

Answer (score 0):

I recommend putting in some kind a messagebox or tracing at the point where it calls Application.Restart to make sure it's really calling it. If you verify that, and it still doesn't work, then could you possibly have something locked and it won't restart until it's closed?